# Why are artifacts in Puzzle Craft 2 not working?

Tags: puzzle-craft

My guess is that items in these rows

- **Magnificent Feathers** gives you a fixed amount of gold
- **Witch's Workshop** gives a bonus in XP gain
- **Tribal Artifacts** unlocks a puzzle

So far I've found 2 items on the second row, and one on the third (the necklace) but I don't feel any extra XP gain (although 5% may not feel like a lot xD) and worse, on the puzzle page **all 5 puzzles** that say "You can unlock this species only by completing a special collection" **still stay grey.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing some more I've realized that you need all 5 items in a collection (5 feathers, 5 masks...) in order to unlock the reward.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually completed these special collections, but they do take time and the randomness at which the artifacts become available is frustrating.
Keep doing the puzzles, particularly at the higher town levels, and the artifacts should eventually appear. My longest time was in the mine in the 5th town, even after I completed all other collections from puzzles in the 6th town.  Crazy.

The XP gain didn't appear for me until after this latest update (18 May).
However, I am still not getting any more of the new species that I would have expected even before the update because there are no more collections being generated (not sure why).
As for special collections, there were to be new ones with the latest update, but have not materialized yet. Not sure if it is a bug or something that I still need to do (get to a higher level, etc.) I'm currently at level 87.